# Android - Change the style of a TextView programatically when the styles are custom and controlled by a theme

Tags: android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am using themes in my android app to control which styles are applied to each element based on the currently selected theme in the manifest.

Within any one theme (of which there may be many) there are a number of styles which I would like to switch between at runtime. For example, i have a style which defines how text should normally look, and another style to define how that same piece of text should look when a code is entered incorrectly.

I cannot reference the @style directly since this is determined by the theme.

I have produced a sample app to illustrate my problem (note that the snippets below ommit some bits and pieces that aren't relevant)

**Attrs.xml:** (My custom resource references so my layouts don't reference styles directly)

```
<resources>
    <attr name="theme_style_one" format="reference" />
    <attr name="theme_style_two" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**Themes.xml:** (Selects the appropriate style to apply based on the theme)

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="ThemeOne" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="theme_style_one">@style/blue</item>
    <item name="theme_style_two">@style/red</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeTwo" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="theme_style_one">@style/green</item>
    <item name="theme_style_two">@style/red</item> 
</style>
</resources>
```

**Styles.xml** (The styles themselves)

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="blue">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="red">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="green">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Colors.xml** (Just some colours)

```
<resources>
      <color name="color_blue">#0000FF</color>
      <color name="color_green">#00FF00</color>
      <color name="color_red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

**activity_main layout:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    style="?theme_style_one" />
```

**activity_main's onCreate:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_text);
    textView.setTextAppearance(this, R.attr.theme_style_two);
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to change the TextView's style to "theme_style_two" programatically. The "SetTextAppearance" command has no effect. I cannot reference the @style/blue directly in this command, because if I changed the theme in the manifest an incorrect style would be applied.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /**
     * Gets a colour attribute for the specified theme attribute
     * 
     * @param The activity context so we can get the theme
     * @param themeAttr The theme attribute we want to get the style attribute for (e.g. R.attr.text_small)
     * @param styleAttr The attribute of the style that we want to get the value for (e.g. android.R.attr.textColor)
     * @return The resource ID of the colour (default is black if the style attribute can't be found)
     */
    public static int GetColourFromThemeAttribute(Context c, int themeAttr, int styleAttr)
    {
        // Get the resource ID of the style that the attribute references for the current theme
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        c.getTheme().resolveAttribute(themeAttr, typedValue, true);

        // Define an array of attributes we want to get from the style
        int[] attributes = new int[] { styleAttr };

        // Get the style attributes from the style that the theme attribute references
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, attributes);

        // Get the colour from the list of style attributes
        int colour = a.getColor(0, Color.BLACK);

        // Release the typed array
        a.recycle();

        return colour;
    }
```